# Delete SQL Record From Within jQuery Dialog

Tags: php, jquery, sql, dialog

I have a table generated from a php while loop displaying records in a file called **userlist.php**. Using data-id, each table now has its SQL record id associated with it.

In my **container.php** file, I have my initial jQuery code which loads **userlist.php** into a div on a 1 second interval. Now, when clicking each separate table, I hide **userlist.php** and show another file in a div called **userdetails.php**, which contains more information about each user.

Now, I am trying to use a jQuery dialog window to show a confirmation message before a record is deleted. In **userdetails.php** you can see an ajax snippet which I have modified based on some suggestions. The problem is that inserting this into the file prevents each table to be clicked at all to show the details. If I remove it, details can be accessed.

Here is my code without the ajax snippet, including it does not allow accessing the details:
[Click Here](http://glokul.us/glokuldev/container.php)

**container.php**

```
<div id="userlist"></div>

<div id="userdetails"></div>

<script>
setInterval(function(){
   $("#userlist").load("userlist.php");
}, 1000);
$('#userdetails').hide();
$(document).on("click",".user", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
      $.get("userdetails.php", {id: id}).done(function(data) {
      $('#userdetails').html(data);
      $('#userdetails').show();
      $('#userlist').hide();
  });
})
$(document).on("click","#back", function() {
  $('#userlist').show();
  $('#userdetails').hide();
});
 </script>
```

**userlist.php**

```
<?php

include 'dbh.php';

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users");

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $color = array("ADMIN"=>"#ebc45b", "MOD"=>"#8fce61", "USER"=>"#9b9ed2");

?>

      <table data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="user" title="User ID: <?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
        <tr>
          <td align="left">User ID:</td>
          <td align="right"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
          <td align="right"><?php echo $row['zip']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><?php echo $row['city']; ?></td>
          <td align="right"><?php echo $row['state']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><span style="color: <?php echo $color[$row['user_level']]; ?>"><?php echo $row['user_level']; ?></span></td>
          <td align="right">"member since..."</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

<?php
  }
}
?>
```

**userdetails.php**

```
<?php

include 'dbh.php';

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=" . $_GET["id"]);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

?>
<div class="menu">
<span id="back">BACK</span>
<span id="delete" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">DELETE</span>
<span id="new">NEW</span>
<span id="edit">EDIT</span>
</div>
<table class="userdetails">
<tr>
  <td align="left">First Name:</td>
  <td align="right"><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="left">Last Name:</td>
  <td align="right"><?php echo $row['last_name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="left">Age:</td>
  <td align="right"><?php echo $row['age']; ?></td>
<tr>
</tr>
  <td align="left">Sex:</td>
  <td align="right"><?php echo $row['sex']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>

//JQ Delete
$(document).on("click","#delete", function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $("#dialog-confirm").data('del-id', id).dialog('open').html('Delete user ' + id + '?');
});

$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
  resizable: false,
  title: 'Confirm Delete',
  height:150,
  modal: true,
  autoOpen:false,
  buttons: {
    'Yes': function() {
      var id = $(this).data('del-id');

      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'deleteuser.php',
        data:{id: id},
      }),


    $('#append').append('Deleted User: ' + id + '<br>');
      $(this).dialog('close');
    },
    'No': function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  }
});

</script>

 <div id="dialog-confirm" style="display:none;"></div>

 <span id="append"></span>

<?php
 }
}
?>
```

**deleteuser.php**

```
<?php
include 'dbh.php';
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id=" . $_POST["id"];

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "User has been deleted!!!";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting user: " . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
```

Just looking for a little help, thank you!

Comment: If you're sending data in post you don't need to also append it to the URL string.

Comment: Removing it had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got this working with:

```
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'deleteuser.php',
    data:{id: id},
  }),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you want:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "deleteuser.php",
    type: "post",
    data: 'deleteuser.php?id=' + id,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      // Close your dialogue on success
    }
  });
```

Hope this helps!